# How to find out the version of the xgboost library on which the model was built

Tags: python, xgboost

I have a question: let's say I have an xgboost model that someone trained and put in a `.pickle` format. I am going to use this model and I need to find out which version of xgboost this model was built on. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The pickle file contains an XGBoost model object in native XGBoost data format (could be binary or JSON). For example, the `xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier` class contains the XGBoost object in its `_Booster` attribute.

The XGBoost object contains `major_version` and `minor_version` integer fields in its header area. This should be the information you want.

TLDR: Consider using the following approach:

1. Extract the XGBoost model object from your pickle file.
2. Is the XGBoost model object encoded in binary or JSON data format? If it is JSON, then you are dealing with XGBoost >= 1.3 version.
3. Parse the XGBoost model object, and extract `major_version` and `minor_version` fields from its header.

Answer (score 0):

xgb_model.save_config() outputs internal parameter configuration as a JSON.

You need to find for "version" attribute.